# Rolling Window for different Groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains date time as an index, and an additional grouping variable `status`. `TUFNWGTP` is a weight, used for comparison across groups

```
            status      shopping        TUFNWGTP
TUDIARYDATE                                     
2003-01-03     emp  0.000000e+00  8155462.672158
2003-01-04     emp  0.000000e+00  1735322.527819
2003-01-04     emp  7.124781e+09  3830527.482672
2003-01-02   unemp  0.000000e+00  6622022.995205
2003-01-09     emp  0.000000e+00  3068387.344956
```

When I was trying to aggregate over month per status, I was doing

```
test = dfNew.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("QS", label='left'), 'status']).sum()
result = pd.DataFrame(test['shopping']/test['TUFNWGTP'], columns=['shopping_weighted'])
result.unstack().plot()
```

[image: quarterly aggregation]

These were fluctuating too much for real time series comparison. I then did the same exercise, grouping by month:

```
test2 = dfNew.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("AS", label='left'), 'status']).sum()
result2 = pd.DataFrame(test2['shopping']/test2['TUFNWGTP'], columns=['shopping_weighted'])
result2.unstack().plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: annual aggregation]

Still spiky. Now I would like to compute a rolling window **for each of the groups in status**. I tried to first compute the quarterly window, and then create a rolling mean over 12 months :

```
pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(test['shopping']/test['TUFNWGTP'], 12).unstack().plot()
plt.show()
```

This gives me the downwards trend more clearly. However, this would give me two time series which look extremely similar for the two different `status` groups, I think that `pandas` is somehow averaging across groups. How should I proceed?

[image: rolling window]

Here's some data for your own reproduction - it's the quarterly aggregated data used for the first graph (`test`):

```
                        shopping      TUFNWGTP
TUDIARYDATE status                            
2003-01-01  emp     8.292987e+12  1.265939e+10
            unemp   8.920840e+11  1.175799e+09
2003-04-01  emp     9.253035e+12  1.338543e+10
            unemp   7.551139e+11  1.131358e+09
2003-07-01  emp     9.237080e+12  1.375033e+10
            unemp   7.440140e+11  1.004834e+09
2003-10-01  emp     1.064579e+13  1.339203e+10
            unemp   1.061342e+12  1.080896e+09
2004-01-01  emp     8.562482e+12  1.284793e+10
            unemp   8.235667e+11  1.169355e+09
2004-04-01  emp     8.773047e+12  1.326451e+10
            unemp   5.907015e+11  1.093678e+09
2004-07-01  emp     9.479579e+12  1.350767e+10
            unemp   1.115300e+12  1.162550e+09
2004-10-01  emp     1.136157e+13  1.375178e+10
            unemp   8.104915e+11  8.251867e+08
2005-01-01  emp     8.105330e+12  1.351932e+10
            unemp   6.082188e+11  1.064661e+09
2005-04-01  emp     9.176033e+12  1.358672e+10
            unemp   8.631214e+11  9.917538e+08
2005-07-01  emp     9.937520e+12  1.414141e+10
            unemp   6.275015e+11  8.850640e+08
2005-10-01  emp     1.044345e+13  1.378072e+10
            unemp   9.742346e+11  9.248803e+08
2006-01-01  emp     9.533602e+12  1.349918e+10
            unemp   5.105317e+11  9.877952e+08
2006-04-01  emp     8.446490e+12  1.349727e+10
            unemp   8.582609e+11  1.007284e+09
2006-07-01  emp     9.167158e+12  1.404490e+10
            unemp   8.219319e+11  9.176818e+08
2006-10-01  emp     1.188230e+13  1.413748e+10
            unemp   1.641259e+12  1.058742e+09
2007-01-01  emp     9.410542e+12  1.408026e+10
            unemp   5.747821e+11  8.084116e+08
2007-04-01  emp     9.492969e+12  1.401190e+10
            unemp   4.231717e+11  9.895104e+08
2007-07-01  emp     9.602594e+12  1.417303e+10
            unemp   7.458046e+11  9.295575e+08
2007-10-01  emp     1.106523e+13  1.449304e+10
            unemp   1.204043e+12  1.112283e+09
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right that

```
pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(test['shopping']/test['TUFNWGTP'], 12).unstack().plot()
```

is mixing values from the two groups. You can see that the first 11 rows are NaNs regardless of `status`:

```
In [82]: pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(test['shopping']/test['TUFNWGTP'], 12)
Out[82]: 
            status
2003-01-01  emp            NaN
            unemp          NaN
2003-04-01  emp            NaN
            unemp          NaN
2003-07-01  emp            NaN
            unemp          NaN
2003-10-01  emp            NaN
            unemp          NaN
2004-01-01  emp            NaN
            unemp          NaN
2004-04-01  emp            NaN
            unemp     1.078546
2004-07-01  emp       1.077651
            unemp     1.086730
2004-10-01  emp       1.050206
```

So instead of using `test`, unstack `test` first so you get two columns -- one for `emp` and one for `unemp`:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(
    test['shopping']/test['TUFNWGTP'], columns=['shopping_weighted'])
result = result.unstack()
print(result.head())
```

yields

```
           shopping_weighted          
status                   emp     unemp
2003-01-01          1.100091  0.871605
2003-04-01          1.188454  1.369590
2003-07-01          0.987842  1.103778
2003-10-01          0.888269  1.133720
2004-01-01          0.950096  1.239608
```

Then apply the rolling_mean to `result`, so you get two columns of rolling means:

```
In [94]: pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(result, 12).head(20)
Out[94]: 
           shopping_weighted          
status                   emp     unemp
...
2005-07-01               NaN       NaN
2005-10-01          0.994440  1.109355
2006-01-01          0.978686  1.128826
2006-04-01          0.964123  1.104678
2006-07-01          0.961347  1.104975
2006-10-01          0.971852  1.111623
2007-01-01          0.973510  1.085946
2007-04-01          0.986782  1.080206
2007-07-01          0.990422  1.095752
2007-10-01          1.006258  1.077732
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1)


dates = pd.date_range('2003-01-03', '2015-03-01', freq='D')
N = len(dates)
index = sorted(np.random.choice(dates, N, replace=True))
status = np.random.choice(['emp', 'unemp'], N, replace=True)
shopping = np.random.random(N)
TUFNWGTP = np.random.random(N)
dfNew = pd.DataFrame({'status': status, 'shopping': shopping, 'TUFNWGTP': TUFNWGTP},
                     index=dates)
mask = dfNew['status'] == 'unemp'
dfNew.loc[mask, 'shopping'] *= 1.1
test = dfNew.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("QS", label='left'), 'status']).sum()
result = pd.DataFrame(
    test['shopping']/test['TUFNWGTP'], columns=['shopping_weighted'])
result = result.unstack()
pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(result, 12).plot()
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Comment: Awesome. One last follow up: `12` means that we take the average over -6M:+6M, right?

Comment: By default, it refers to the average over the previous 12 periods. That is why you see 11 NaNs before the first value. If you use `center=True` however, then the value reported is the mean over 6 prior periods, the current period and 5 succeeding periods. (The rolling mean is placed in the center of the window when `center=True`.)

Comment: If you group by `QS` (quarter start frequency) then each period is a quarter (3 months). So 12 periods spans 36 months.